# How to clear previously opened activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Payment.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Opening coupon activity to apply coupon:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Payment.this, Coupon.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

From coupon activity opening payment activity with updated data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Coupon.this, Payment.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is, when I click on the back button on payment activity after applying the coupon, it opens the previously opened payment activity again (not the main activity).

onBackPressed() I don't want to do it static (like Intent intent = new Intent(Payment.this, MainActivity.class); and also don't want to use finish(); in payment activity.

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you want to call the MainActivity from onBackPressed or call finish()?

Comment: Because Payment activity opens from more than one activities

Comment: How do you start your application? From an IDE (Android Studio) or from the installer?

Comment: Try this please: launch `Payment`, then `Coupon`, then `Payment` again. Before pressing BACK button, use `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`, find the task stack for your app and paste that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` when launching the Payment activity.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Answer (score 0):

This is a Simple Use case of [`startActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) don't make it complicated with Intent Flags and launch modes.

Whenever you Open your Activity `Coupon` just use  `startActivityForResult` and upon applying coupon send the result back to previous Activity (success/failure) or whatever result you want . Then you can change the UI as per the result you got in `onActivityResult()` .
You can follow [How to manage startActivityForResult on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android) or the latest way from the doc [Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) .